# Debugging with the editor and persisting user login

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

So I am using the Facebook SDK with Unity  -
Two Questions:

1 - I am assuming that the SDK will cache the Token so that, the next time I launch the app the user is already signed in, correct, or do I have to cache the token myself?

2 - When I try to login with the Editor in run mode (debugger), I get prompted with the "Mock Login Dialog".
I would like to test the scenario that the user is already logged in Facebook is there a way for me to set a debug token and avoid the mock dialog to show up?

Thanks.